# ZIO 2013: Dolls

Tags: algorithm

Your shop sells several different types of dolls. Each doll has a suggested price, and no
two types of doll have the same price. You would like to fix an actual selling price for
each doll so that dolls of different types are as different in price as possible. Due to
some government regulations, you can only modify the suggested price within a fixed
band of ±K—in other words, if the suggested price is p, you can pick any selling price
in the range {p− K, p− K + 1, . . . , p+ K −1, p+ K}. Of course, the selling price must
always be non-negative.
For instance, suppose there are four types of dolls with suggested prices 130, 210, 70
and 90 and you are allowed to modify prices within a band of 20. Then, you can adjust
the prices to 150, 210, 50 and 100, respectively, so that the minimum difference in price
between any two types of dolls is 50. (For the second doll, you could have picked any
price between 200 and 230.) You can check that this is the largest separation that you
can achieve given the constraint.

In each of the cases below, you are given a sequence of prices and the value of K. You
have to determine the maximum separation that you can achieve between all pairs in
the sequence if you are allowed to modify each price by upto ±K.

> (a) K = 13. Sequence: 144, 152, 214, 72, 256, 3, 39, 117, 238, 280.
>   (b) K = 10. Sequence: 10, 48, 57, 32, 61, 74, 33, 45, 99, 81, 19, 24, 101.
>   (c) K = 20. Sequence: 10, 19, 154, 67, 83, 39, 54, 110, 124, 99, 139, 170

So basically, I just need to find the value of maximum separation *without coding*. I tried to devise an algorithm, but failed miserably, so I just started brute forcing it, by basically increasing/decreasing each of the prices by a certain value, but the bruteforcing applied here is just too tough due to the value of K. (It would have been simple for any K<6).

Can someone define a function or recurrence relation to calculate it? The solutions are up online, but they only give the answer as an integer and don't explain how to reach the solution. I am a beginner in programming, so try explaining using pseudocode/ little bit of C++, please. Thank you.

Source: http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2013/zio2013/zio2013-qpaper.pdf
Solution: http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2013/zio2013/zio2013-solutions.pdf

Comment: The fact that this needs to be solved "without coding" makes it not a good fit for SE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems like a better fit for [Programmers SE](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MTCoster Greetings! Please read my question carefully. I demanded an algorithm/recurrence relation in pseudocode/C++ or an algorithm. The 'without coding' part was an explanation to why solutions are unavailable elsewhere, namely, that the format of the competition is such that you are supposed to solve programming/algorithmic questions without actually having any prerequisite knowledge of coding. This is a question from the ZIO, one of the methods to select the Indian team for the IOI, which is one of the most prestigious high school programming competitions.

Comment: @Stedy This is a question from the ZIO, one of the methods to select the Indian team for the IOI, which is one of the most prestigious high school programming competitions. It has nothing to do with software engineering in any way. I have requested an algorithm for a competitive programming question, which can easily be implemented in programming. I believe it would be voted as off topic in the SE forum. Please stop unnecessarily downvoting questions. Competitive programming is a highly interesting aspect of programming, and I see no reason why it doesn't fit in a programming forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a O(nlogn) algorithm.

To illustrate I will use the second example: 10, 48, 57, 32, 61, 74, 33, 45, 99, 81, 19, 24, 101 with K=10

1. Sort the list (10, 19, 24, 32, 33, 45, 48, 57, 61, 74, 81, 99, 101)
2. Use bisection to find the minimum separation x

For a trial value of x, assign the final values greedily placing them as small as possible while satisfying the conditions (non-negative, within K of original value, at least x greater than previous).

So let us start with x=10.
We will move as follows:

1. 10->0 (can't go negative so this is smallest allowed)
2. 19->10 (can't go within K=10 of the previous value)
3. 24->20
4. 32->30
5. 33->40
6. 45->50
7. 48 becomes impossible.  We can only assign values between 38 and 58, but none of these are more than 10 away from the previous 50.

We conclude that x=10 is too high a separation and we need to move lower.
You might try x=7 and find it is possible, x=9 find it is impossible, then try x=8:

1. 10->0
2. 19->9 (can only move to values 9->29)
3. 24->17
4. 32->25
5. 33->33
6. 45->41
7. 48->49
8. 57->56
9. 61->64
10. 74->72
11. 81->80
12. 99->89
13. 101->97

And so we have found that x=8 is possible, x=9 is impossible and therefore x=8 is the maximum possible separation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked out the other 2 as well!